# Aharonov-Bohm ring with many electrons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, fermions, hamiltonian

4 electrons are in an [Aharonov-Bohm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect) ring which the Hamiltonian is given by,

$$H=\dfrac {\hbar^2} {2mr^{2}}\sum _{n=1}^{4}\left( -i\dfrac {\partial } {\partial \theta_{n}}-4\right) ^{2}$$

How to obtain the ground state wave-function. I know that single electron states are given by,

$\phi(\theta)=\frac{1}{2\pi}$$ e^{im\theta}$

Also, given that the ground state is unique. Does that means $S=0$ for ground state? so Can I written down the wave-function as a Slatter determinant?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is a Slater determinant.

Comment: So can I get the slatter determinant of only orbital wave-functions? because spin wave-function is symmetric  ?